# Servicestack Opentelemetry integration

Tags: servicestack, open-telemetry

We want to integrate Open Telemetry into our Servicestack API.

The requests via the AspNetCoreInstrumentation are displayed correctly in JaegerUI, but I don't see the additional span added to track the access to the user store

I've got the following setup:

Programm.cs:

```
    var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices(services => {
               services.AddOpenTelemetry()
                        .WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
                            tracerProviderBuilder
                                .AddSource(Diagnostics.ServiceName)
                                .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                                    .AddService(Diagnostics.ServiceName))
                                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                                .AddConsoleExporter()
                                .AddJaegerExporter());
```

IDiagonstics:

```
public interface IDiagnostics
{
    Tracer Tracer { get; set; }
}
```

Setup Diagnostics

```
private void SetupDiagnostics(Container container)
{
   TracerProvider.Default.GetTracer(Diagnostics.ServiceName);

   var diag = new Diagnostics()
   {
       Tracer = TracerProvider.Default.GetTracer(Diagnostics.ServiceName)
   };
   Container.AddSingleton<IDiagnostics>(diag);
}
```

Manager:

```
public class UserManager
{
  public IDiagnostics Diagnostics { get; set; }
      
  public void SetupUser(string email) 
  {
     using var span = Diagnostics.Tracer.StartActiveSpan("read user store");
        
     // do stuff and track as individual span inside aspnetcore instrument span
    
  }
}
```

We would like to see the second span for "read  user store" as a sub-span of the aspnetcore instrument span.
What are we missing or is there a conceptual issue?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Don't forget that the AddJaegerExporter is about to be deprecated https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger/README.md

Answer (score 4):

You're using OpenTelemetry .NET's "shim" API described [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Api#introduction-to-opentelemetry-net-tracing-api). The recommendation is to use .NET's Activity API directly.

I can describe how you might get things working using the shim API, but first I'd like to cover how things would look using the Activity API instead.

In the example below, .NET's `ActivitySource` and `Activity` are synonymous in OpenTelemetry terminology with `Tracer` and `Span`, respectively. For brevity, I've simplified things a bit and I have not encapsulated the `ActivitySource` into an instance of `IDiagnostics`.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

public class UserManager
{
    private static ActivitySource activitySource =
        new ActivitySource(Diagnostics.ServiceName);
      
    public void SetupUser(string email) 
    {
        using var activity = activitySource.StartActivity("read user store");
        
        // do stuff and track as individual span inside aspnetcore instrument span
        // Note that activity may be null here in case it was not sampled.
        activity?.AddTag("some_tag", "some_value");
    }
}
```

The default behavior of `StartActivity` in the above code will be to use `Activity.Current` as the parent of the new `Activity`. Assuming `UserManager.SetupUser` is invoked in the context of a request, `Activity.Current` should be the `Activity` created by ASP.NET Core and you will see the correct parent/child relationship.

---

That said, if you really want to use the shim API, the issue you have is that [`StartActiveSpan`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/fea6793a5590a18ff6d5e99460f9dfd8cf4c95b2/src/OpenTelemetry.Api/Trace/Tracer.cs#L140) defaults to creating a root span (i.e., no parent).

You would want to use this [other overload of `StartActiveSpan`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/fea6793a5590a18ff6d5e99460f9dfd8cf4c95b2/src/OpenTelemetry.Api/Trace/Tracer.cs#L124) and explicitly pass in the parent span. Something like:

```cs
using var span = Diagnostics.Tracer.StartActiveSpan(
    "read user store",
    SpanKind.Internal,
    Diagnostics.Tracer.CurrentSpan);
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, but If I use your ActivitySource / Activity approach, the activity after activitiySource.StartActivity("xyz") is "null". I don't see why. If I check "Activity.Current" I can see the correct Activity which leads me to believe that the request context is correct

Comment: If it's null then that suggests either the activity was not sampled or you're missing `tracerProviderBuilder.AddSource("NameOfMyActivitySource")`.

Comment: thats my issue yes. It seems like its not sampled, but i don't know why this is.

Comment: If you have a minimal repro you could share, I could take a look. There's not enough to go on here to understand why it may not be getting sampled.

Comment: Your idea to create a minmal repo led me to the right track. Services & Jet Brains Rider have a bug, which we fixed in code
https://forums.servicestack.net/t/info-rider-2022-3-2-required-adding-configureprofiling/11346
After removing this profiling "fix" the sample is correctly correlated!